# How to remove style on click of a button

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular13

I have a button which is inside an ngFor loop. I am styling it like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let component of componentList;let index =index">
    <button type="button" id='Button{{index}}' name='Button{{index}}' class="device_name_button"  [ngClass]="{'greencolorstyle':component.status=='Available', 'redcolorstyle': component.status=='Faulted', 'graycolorstyle':component.status=='Unavailable','myClass':isClicked==true}" (click)="selectComponent($event,component.components);" > {{component.name}} </button>
</div>
```

I am setting *isClicked = true* with click event handler.

My problem is that when I see the style being applied on the button, after a click, I see, *'device_name_button greencolorstyle myClass'*. Whereas on click it should only have *'device_name_button'* and *'myClass'*.

How do I remove the other classes from this button when someone clicks on this button?

Comment: can you add the code you execute on click

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it using two step process. First I created a custom-component named "custom-button". I replaced the button element in the Html with custom element. In this way I had a handle on each item of the array. Then I created three more styles namely "graywhitecolorstyle","greenwhitecolorstyle" & "redwhitecolorstyle", over and above the three already mentioned.

Next the html of custom-button component.

```
<div class="device_name_button"  matTooltipPosition="right"
[ngClass]="{'whiteredbackground':hardwareComponent.isClicked && 
hardwareComponent.status=='Faulted' 
,'greencolorstyle':hardwareComponent.status=='Available' && 
hardwareComponent.isClicked==false,'greenwhitecolorstyle':
hardwareComponent.status=='Available' && hardwareComponent.isClicked, 
'redcolorstyle': hardwareComponent.status=='Faulted' && 
!hardwareComponent.isClicked,
'graycolorstyle':hardwareComponent.status=='Unavailable' && 
!hardwareComponent.isClicked,'graywhitecolorstyle':
hardwareComponent.status=='Unavailable' && hardwareComponent.isClicked}"
(click)="selectHardware()" ><p>{{title}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complex answer which does not follow Angular best practices, just in case any other users happen to find this.

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of possible solutions.

1. You update the status of the component in the array. Your `ngClass` binding will do the rest. This is what I recommend, as it means your view depends only on the data, but I understand that it is not always easy to mutate an element in an array.
2. You set your `ngClass` conditions differently in order to apply your color classes according to both the status of the component AND isClicked.

Secondly, you shouldn't be using string interpolation in your attributes. You should be using attribute binding: `[id]="'Button' + index"`.

Comment: I have modified the model class and added isClicked property. And I have added two ngClass elements. This time, the button is always white background.

  <button type="button" class="device_name_button" id='{{index}}' name='Button{{index}}'
         [ngClass]="{'greencolorstyle':component.status=='Available', 'redcolorstyle': component.status=='Faulted', 'graycolorstyle':component.status=='Unavailable'}"
         [ngClass]="{'myClass':component.isClicked}" 
         (click)="selectHardwareComponent($event,component)" > {{component.name}} </button>

Comment: I am changing the IsClicked to true in the click event handler,
   this.hardwareDetails=_hardwareComponent.components;
 
    _hardwareComponent.isClicked=true;
    let index = this.componentList.indexOf(_hardwareComponent);
    this.componentList[index].isClicked=true;
  }